# TypeORM second JOIN statement does not provide results

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have a database with products, manufacturers and collections. The products and manufacturers are connected with a n:m relation. In a collection users can store products, so the products and collections are also connected with a n:m relation.

Now I have to load the products with their manufacturer depending on the collectionId.

Currently I have the following snippet:

```
CollectionProducts.createQueryBuilder("cp")
    .innerJoinAndSelect("cp.product", "product")
    .leftJoinAndSelect(
      Manufacturer,
      "manufacturer",
      "product.manufacturerId = manufacturer.id"
    )
    .where("cp.collectionId IN(:...ids)", { ids: collectionIds })
    .getMany();
```

The products are loaded successfully, but the manufacturers are not loaded.

Here is the printed out result:

```
[
  CollectionProducts {
    collectionId: 1,
    productId: 1,
    __product__: Product {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Tea',
      productImage: '',
      description: 'Peach',
      releaseDate: 2021-10-19T18:13:42.938Z,
      status: null,
      origin: 'Germany',
      manufacturerId: 1
    }
  }
]
```

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution for my specific problem. Instead of using `getMany()` I had to use `getRawMany()`. The generated SQL itself was correct, with `getRawMany()` I got all the results needed.